# Add href link to Image that has been displayed via js click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Similar to a question I asked recently but the previous was using mouse over so was rubbish for touch screen.

This is 3 divs with images. on click they individually change to a second image and reset the other 2 to a standard image. this all works ok.

But when the second image in any of the divs is active i would like to be able to click this image and navigate to a different page.

Clearly adding href to the html just navigates and ignores the JS effect.

Thanks for reading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#s1').click(function(){
         $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/click-1.png');
          $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-2.jpg');
           $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-3.jpg');
     });
     $('#s2').click(function(){
         $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-1.jpg');
          $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/click-2.png');
           $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-3.jpg');
     });
     $('#s3').click(function(){
          $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-1.jpg');
           $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-2.jpg');
            $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/click-3.png');
     });


});


<div id="section3" class="container-fluid" align="center">
    <div class="row row-centered ">

    <div id="top-box-1" class="col-sm-4"> 
    <img src="images/object/standard-1.jpg" class="std" id="s1" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-2" class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="images/object/standard-2.jpg" class="std "id="s2" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-3" class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="images/object/standard-3.jpg" class="std" id="s3" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Clearly adding href to the html just navigates and ignores the JS effect." Can you explain that? Why can't you just wrap the images in an anchor tag?

Comment: <div id="top-box-1" class="col-sm-4"> 
   <a href="www.where-ever"> <img src="images/object/standard-1.jpg" class="std" id="s1" width="300" height="300"/></a>
    </div> If i did this then the click would go to the www.where-ever and the image would not change. Im a bit of a noob so i miss the obvious sometimes

Comment: not sure what wrapping in an anchor tag is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if the `src` now contains 'click'. if not then swap the `src` and `return false` to stop the href:-

```js
$('#s1').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).is('[src*="click"]')) {
    $('#s1').attr('src', 'images/object/click-1.png');
    $('#s2').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-2.jpg');
    $('#s3').attr('src', 'images/object/standard-3.jpg');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="section3" class="container-fluid" align="center">
  <div class="row row-centered ">

    <div id="top-box-1" class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="images/object/standard-1.jpg" class="std" id="s1" width="300" height="300" />
      </a>
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-2" class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="images/object/standard-2.jpg" class="std " id="s2" width="300" height="300" />
      </a>
    </div>


    <div id="top-box-3" class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="images/object/standard-3.jpg" class="std" id="s3" width="300" height="300" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

To break this down: `if (!$(this).is('[src*="click"]')) {`

`$(this).is` allows you to check `this` against a selector, returning a boolean (true) if it does.

`'[src*="click"]'` is the selector to determine if the `src` attribute contains 'click'. Where the `*` means contains anywhere. There are other combinations like `^=` for starts with.

Therefore `$(this).is('[src*="click"]')` means true if the `src` has 'click'. But you need to invert this to **not** contains. That's what the `!` is for, meaning if `this` (the clicked element) has not got 'click' in the `src`.

Comment: Thanks Ben this fits what i need perfectly, I will however now need to learn why it works or i will always be asking questions ;0) Cant up vote because im new to the site.

Comment: @Huckster i've just updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @BenG, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already handling the click event, you'll likely want to perform this logic in that same event.  Something structurally like this:

```
if (/* some condition */) {
    window.location.href = someUrl;
}
```

I guess you'd need to define what that condition is.  Would it be based on the current `src` of the image?  Something like this?:

```
if ($(this).attr('src') === 'images/object/click-1.png') {
    window.location.href = someUrl;
}
```

(You'd also have to define what `someUrl` is, of course.)

Comment: Many thanks David this seems like a good solution to me but it just would work in my page, Many thanks for your input.